# Java modulos and division difference

Tags: java

```
2 / 4 = 0; // it should be 0.5, but the result is 0

2 % 4 = 2 // its should be 0, cuz there are no remainders, but somehow the result is 2
```

Why it gives this results, what I'am doing wrong?

Comment: "Integer arithmetic"

Comment: because java doesn't support auto type casting.

Comment: what should I use the proper result?

Comment: Use 2.0 / 4. One of the values has to be a literal floating point type.

Comment: "what should I use the proper result?" => sounds like you might want to read up on how floating point works; it'll give you a proper for these numbers, but floating point numbers are always approximations.  It's good to understand how they work, or you'll get bitten many times in the future.

Comment: 2/4 = 0.5 -- If its int, it just takes 0 & 2 % 4 returns remainder..

Comment: @chiastic-security the question is so basic that you can find it at least 200 times on SO.

Comment: I really hate it when people down vote because a question is too basic. But of course sometimes some questions deserved to be down voted because the person who asked do not even bother to do a 1 minute research.

Answer (score 4):

For the first one: since `2` and `4` are integers, this is doing *integer division*, which means any fractional part is discarded. It gets rounded down. If you want to force it to be floating point, you want `2/4.0` or `2.0/4`. Now one of them is a floating point `double` rather than an `int`, so the result is also a `double`.

For the second one: when you divide 2 by 4, you get 0 remainder 2, so the answer is `2`. I suspect you're thinking of dividing 4 by 2, in which case the remainder certainly is 0, so if you try `4 % 2` you'll get `0` as the result.

Comment: +1 but personally I like to see the "doctored" literal first (to improve readability) so I'd have 2.0 / 4. Also, I find `(double)2 / 4` loathsome since some hotshot will, one day, refactor to `(double)(2 / 4)` and you're back where you started.

Comment: @Bathsheba I have added that in to humour you :)

Answer (score 1):

The result of dividing two `int`(s) is an `int`. Change one argument to a `double`, like

```
double v = ((double) 2 / 4);
System.out.println(v);
```

And you'll get

```
0.5
```

Finally (for modulus), the 4 goes into 2 `0` times. And, `2 - (4*0)` = 2; so the modulus operation (or remainder) is correct.